# how to create a business logic in javascript with multiple if then else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I would like to know what is optimal way of constructing logic if there are multiple "if then else statements" in javascript.

For example I have list of documents in json format like below:

`[{"document":"Registration Certificate"},{"document":"Conditional Approval Certificate"},{"document":"Compliance Certificate"}]`.

For simplicity sake (my requirements are): Construct html table from  the answers that were selected in the form  and provide list of the documents that user will have to provide:

Q1.Is your vehicle registered?
Q2.Is your vehicle road worthy?
Q3.Does your vehicle comply to road standards?

For example
Scenario 1: if the user answered "Y" to Q1 and Q3 I will need to show Registration certificate and Compliance certificate.

Scenario 2: if the user answered "Y" to Q2 and Q3 I will need to show Conditional Approval Certificate and Compliance certificate.

Below is what I have attempted (pseudo code in js) should I continue like this? I am worried as the combinations could become quite extensive and I will be repeating lot of code.

```
var tblRequiredDocs="<table>"
if(Q1 == "Yes"){
  tblRequiredDocs+= "<tr><td>Registration Certificate</td></tr>" 
}
if(Q2 == "Yes"){
  tblRequiredDocs+= "<tr><td>Conditional Approval Certificate</td></tr>" 
}
tblRequirements+="</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a switch case, really good and look way better than multiple ifs. don't forget to return the value for each case, also your case and have multi options using || && depending on each use case as you stated in your question, simply you can gain more control over each case.

```js
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
     day = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
}
```